# semantic Versioning for plugins

Tags: plugins, version

I have an application that support plugins. both use semantic Versioning. I want to see which way is better to manage the plugin version compatibility.  The goal is that application should  not load any plugins that are not compatible with current version. Keep in mind that  plugins could be developed by somebody else.

The approach I took now works like this:

The plugins will define SupportedVersions.  For example, the Application version is 1.10.34.    the SupportedVersions could be 1.09,1.10.   So the application will only load the plugin if the SupportedVersions includes the application's current version.

The problem for this approach is, every time the application has a new version, need to add that to the plugin's SupportedVersions.  We could say if the Major version is the same, we can load the plugin, but the Majar version of the application changes does not mean it break up the compatibility with the plugin, right?

So, any better approach than that?